# Visualizing elevation profile across a whole mosaic dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, lidar, 3d-analyst, profile, mosaic-dataset

I'm working with many DEMs derived from LiDAR data (IMG format) in a mosaic dataset. This allows me to create hillshade (or shaded relief) functions to display the data, which is great.

However it won't let me extract an elevation profile using the 3D analyst toolbar. Ideas?

I can get the profile tool to work on an individual DEM, but not across the mosaic dataset as a whole. (note: this dataset is too big to combine into a single raster).

Comment: You need to have 3d analyst turned on to activate the profile tool, is your extension enabled in ArcMap? Mosaic datasets do not store LiDAR, they store raster, so you have a DEM not LiDAR you're trying to profile. You may need to export your raster (mosaic dataset) to raster (raster dataset like TIFF or IMG) for it to be suitable for the profile tool.

Comment: Yes 3d analyst is turned on and enabled. Thanks for the clarification, the mosaic dataset is a mosaic of many DEMs derived from LiDAR data (IMG format) and is not LiDAR (LAS files). I can get profile tool to work on an individual DEM, but not across the mosaic dataset as a whole. (note: this dataset is too big to combine into a single raster.

Comment: I think that a Mosaic Dataset might not be suitable for the profile tool, if this is the case you will need to use either a single IMG tile or extract (Clip Management http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000009n000000 - does not need Spatial Analyst licence).. here is a blog that might interest you https://www.edc.uri.edu/blog/mosaic-datasets-and-lidar-data-advanced-processing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recording height profile from raster along a polyline shapefile?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202338/recording-height-profile-from-raster-along-a-polyline-shapefile)

Comment: I don't believe this is duplicate - this is question is regarding data stored in mosaic dataset, the other is not

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround solution, you can interpolate a line from your mosaic dataset using the 'interpolate line' tool.  You can then use the output line to create the profile.
According to this post: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/62956, the first line you interpolate may take some time, but all subsequent lines will process quickly.