# Recording height profile from raster along a polyline shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, line, lidar, profile

I'm looking for the easiest way to record a series of raster values along a 400 meter transect in ArcGIS 10.3.1. I'm working with a LiDAR canopy height model with 3mx3m cells where each cell represents the height of the highest LiDAR return within that area. I'm hoping to produce an output similar to an elevation profile that shows the variation in canopy heights across a specific transect. I also want to show how the variations in canopy height are reflected by other layers generated through grey-level correlation matrix calculations (also a simple raster).

The goal is to create a chart that looks similar to this:

[image]

What is the easiest way to go about this in ArcGIS? I don't know anything about coding, but this seems like something that should be easy to do in Arc.

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: [profile viewing in ArcGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25109/how-to-calculate-an-elevation-profile-for-a-polyline-in-arcgis-10-with-spatial-a) and [profile viewing and recording with open source software](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/code-to-calculate-elevation-profile-along-line-from-a-dem).

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool in the 3D analyst toolbox called [Interpolate Shape](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/interpolate-shape.htm) that will do this:

[image]

According to ESRI, the tool description is:

> The Interpolate Shape tool converts a 2D point, polyline, or polygon feature class into a 3D feature class by interpolating z-values for input features from a surface. The input surface can either be a raster, triangulated irregular network (TIN), or terrain dataset. Attributes from the input are copied to the output.

There are several options for performing the z-values interpolation. Learn more about them [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/how-interpolate-shape-works.htm).